# Net 6 ConsoleApp multiple BlockingCollection<T> huge CPU consumption

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-core, blockingcollection

I have a Net 6 Console app where I use several BlockingCollections to process files that are dropped in a folder. I watch the folder using Net's `FileWatcher()`.

In the Created event, I use a `Channel` to handle the processing, which is done in two phases, and after each phase the result item is moved to a BlockingCollection, that will then be consumed by the next phase.

Program.cs

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   BlockingCollection<FileMetadata> _fileMetaDataQueue = new BlockingCollection<FileMetadata>()
   var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<FileSystemEventArgs>();     

   // Start a task to monitor the channel and process notifications
   var notificationProcessor = Task.Run(() => ProcessNotifications(channel, _fileMetaDataQueue));

   Task fileCopyingTask = Task.Run(() => fileCopyThread.Start()); //injected using DI

   Task processMovedFile = Task.Run(() => ProcessDestinationThread.Start()); //injected using DI

   Task retryOnErrorTask = Task.Run(() => RetryOnErrorThread.Start()); //injected using DI
   using var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(sourceFolder); //C:\temp
   // other fw related config
   watcher.Created += (sender, e) => channel.Writer.WriteAsync(e);
}

private async Task ProcessNotifications(Channel<FileSystemEventArgs> channel, BlockingCollection<FileMetadata> queue)
{
   await foreach (var e in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
   {
      Thread.Sleep(300); // So the file is released after it is dropped
      try
      {
         // Process the file and add its name and extension to the queue                
         FileMetaData fileInfo = ExtractFileMetadata(e.FullPath); //processing method               
         queue.Add(fileInfo);
      }
      try
      {
         // logging etc
      }
   }           
}
```

The BlockingCollection `queue` is then consumed in the FileCopyThread class, with the Start() method exposed (and called)

FileCopyThread.cs

```
BlockingCollection<FileMetadata> resultQueue = new();
BlockingCollection<FileMetadata> retryQueue = new();

public async Task Start()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        ProcessQueue();
   });
}

private void ProcessQueue()
{
    // Since IsCompleted is never set, it will always run
    while (!fileMetadataQueue.IsCompleted)
    {
        // Try to remove an item from the queue
        if (fileMetadataQueue.TryTake(out FileMetadata result))
        {
           // Copy the file to a new location
           var newFileLocation = processorOps.MoveFile(result); // move file to other path
                    
           // Add the new file location to the result queue
           if (newFileLocation != String.Empty) 
           { 
               result.newFileLocation = newFileLocation;
               resultQueue.Add(result); 
           }
           else {                      
              retryQueue.Add(result);                        
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ProcessDestinationThread` and `RetryOnErrorThread` work in exactly the same way, but do some different processing, and consume the `resultQueue` and the `retryQueue`, respectively.
Now when I run this app, it works fine, everything gets processed as expected, but my CPU and power usage is between 85% and 95%, which is huge, IMO, and does so even when it is not processing anything, just sitting idle. I figured this is because all the infinite loops, but how can I remedy this?
Birds eye view: What I would like is that in case the `filewatcher.created` event is not firing (ie no files are dropped) then the all the queues after it can be running in idle, so to speak. No need for constant checking, then.

I thought about calling `CompleteAdding()` on the `BlockingCollection<T>`, but it seems that I cannot reverse that. And the app is supposed to run indefinitely: So if the drop folder is empty, it might be receiving new files at any time.

Is there a way how I can reduce the CPU usage of my application?

Ps. I am aware that this code is not a fully working example. The real code is far more complex than this, and I had to remove a lot of stuff that is distracting. If you think any pieces of relevant code are missing, I can provide them. I hope this code will at least make clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem is caused by TryTake().  You have nothing useful to do when it returns false, except call TryTake() again.  So that burns 100% core with no accomplishment.  Use Take().

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> private void ProcessQueue()
> {
>    while (!fileMetadataQueue.IsCompleted)
>    {
>        if (fileMetadataQueue.TryTake(out FileMetadata result))
>        {
>            //...
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```

This pattern for consuming a `BlockingCollection<T>` is incorrect. It causes a tight loop that burns unproductively a CPU core. The correct pattern is to use the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) method:

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
    foreach (FileMetadata result in fileMetadataQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```